# powerBI Python visuals, how to have two different datasets

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have different tables in my powerBI report, I have some problems using python visuals.
The problem is that I want to import in the python script two tables in two deifferent datasets.
Is that possible?

I tried to select the columns from the two different tables but in the script I always see only one dataset